# std::function cannot deduce overloaded type in template instance

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

I have this fairly simple template class :

```
template <typename Value>
struct Foo {
    typedef Value ValueType;
    Value array[3];
};
```

Now I am trying  to get a function object (`std::function`) from a simple function using the dependent type of `F` as function argument and return types.

```
template <typename F>
void floorfunc(const F& foo) {
    typedef typename F::ValueType Value;
    auto fptr = std::function<Value(Value)>(std::floor);
}
```

The compiler correctly instantiates the `Value` types but fails to guess the correct function overload of `floor`, and sends me this error message

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::function<float(float)>::function(<unresolved overloaded function type>
```

How do I tell the compiler wich overload needs to be used in that case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a cast:

```
std::function<Value(Value)>(static_cast<Value(&)(Value)>(std::floor))
```

`std::floor` is overloaded, and the constructor of `std::function` is a template, so there's no obvious choice of overload and you have to specify it explicitly, which you can do with the cast.

Comment: Can't it be wrapped in a lambda too? For example, `std::function<float (float)>([](float f) { return std::floor(f); });`.

Comment: I just tried it since you asked and it seems to work (Visual Studio 2013).